# Getting inverse of polynoms with trigonometric functions

Tags: functions, inverse

I'm trying to get the inverse of $$f(x) = \cos(x) + 3x$$

I tried it by definition of $\cos(x)$ with no luck:

$$\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!}+...$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there exists no explicit inverse, but an impplicit one is as follow by exchanging "x-y":
$$\large y=\cos x+3x\overbrace{\longrightarrow}^{x\leftrightarrow y} x=\cos y+3y$$
Or in a suitable format as:
$$\cos (f^{-1}(x))+3f^{-1}(x)=x$$
As:
$$f(f^{-1}x)=x$$
So:
$$f'(f^{-1}x).(f^{-1})'(x)=1$$
Since $y$ is a monotonically strictly increasing function and little guessing after drawing its rough sketch maybe you'll recognize:
$$f^{-1}(1)=0$$
So:
$$f'(f^{-1}(1))(f^{-1}(1))'=1$$
Or:
$$(f^{-1}(1))'=1/f'(0)=1/3$$

Comment: So, how can I calculate $f^{-1}(1)$ and $(f^{-1})$'$(1)$ ?

Comment: @IurySimões for $f^{-1}(1)$ you should try to draw a graph of $f(x)$ and see if that clears it up for you. For $(f^{-1})'(1)$, use the chain rule on the defining relation for an inverse function: $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$.

Comment: @IurySimões see the edit!

Comment: Thks. I'll see it with more calm qhen I came back late. Thks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

As Aditya answered, there is no analytical inverse fo your function. However, if,as you tried, you can approximate locally your function by a series, you can inverse the series. Suppose you have $$y=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$$ (you know the $a_i$'s) you could, at least under some conditions, write $$x=\sum_{j=0}^m b_j y^j$$ replace in the first series, develop and cancel as much terms as you can to get the $b_j$'s.

Taking your example $$y=\cos(x) + 3x=1+3
   x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{720}+O\left(x^7\right)$$ you should arrive to $$x=\frac{y-1}{3}+\frac{1}{54} (y-1)^2+\frac{1}{486}
   (y-1)^3+\frac{(y-1)^4}{8748}-\frac{(y-1)^5}{78732}-\frac{2
   (y-1)^6}{295245}+O\left((y-1)^7\right)$$

Comment: Thks a lot. Claude

Comment: You are very welcome !